# pyglet "Unable to share contexts" exception when running PsychoPy demo twice

Tags: pyglet, psychopy

PsychoPy looks like just what I need.  But I want to use my own development environment (a straightforward IPython prompt combined with the editor of my choice) instead of the provided IDE.

The trouble is that you seem to have to quit Python and relaunch after every PsychoPy run.  If for example I `cd` to the `...../demos/coder/stimuli` directory and type `run gabor.py` it runs fine,  but if I then type `run gabor.py` again I get this exception from pyglet:

```
C:\snap\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\pyglet\window\win32\__init__.pyc in _create(self)
    259         if not self._wgl_context:
    260             self.canvas = Win32Canvas(self.display, self._view_hwnd, self._dc)
--> 261             self.context.attach(self.canvas)
    262             self._wgl_context = self.context._context
    263

C:\snap\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\pyglet\gl\win32.pyc in attach(self, canvas)
    261         self._context = wglext_arb.wglCreateContextAttribsARB(canvas.hdc,
    262             share, attribs)
--> 263         super(Win32ARBContext, self).attach(canvas)

C:\snap\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\pyglet\gl\win32.pyc in attach(self, canvas)
    206                 raise RuntimeError('Share context has no canvas.')
    207             if not wgl.wglShareLists(share._context, self._context):
--> 208                 raise gl.ContextException('Unable to share contexts')
    209
    210     def set_current(self):

ContextException: Unable to share contexts
```

Is there some sort of `pyglet.cleanup()` I can call (analogous to `pygame.quit()`) to allow PsychoPy scripts to run more than once in the same session?  Or other way of avoiding this problem?

I'm using the Standalone PsychoPy distro version 1.81.02, untouched. The problem is not specific to IPython---it also can also be demonstrated from the plain Python prompt if you disable `sys.exit` and type `execfile('gabor.py')` twice:

```
C:\snap\PsychoPy2\Lib\site-packages\PsychoPy-1.81.02-py2.7.egg\psychopy\demos\coder\stimuli>python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> import sys; sys.exit = lambda x:x
>>> execfile('gabor.py')
0.6560  WARNING         Movie2 stim could not be imported and won't be available
1.6719  WARNING         Monitor specification not found. Creating a temporary one...
>>>
>>> execfile('gabor.py')
Traceback (most recent call last):
[snip]
  File "C:\snap\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\pyglet\gl\win32.py", line 208, in attach
    raise gl.ContextException('Unable to share contexts')
pyglet.gl.ContextException: Unable to share contexts
```

Comment: there is a `pyglet.window.Window.close()` which deletes all the context of the current window, but this has to be run on the object that iniated the window itself. so you'll need to place your initated `Window()` in a variable and call `.close()` on it. I assume this is of little help however since you're running it inside some sort of wrapper?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to undo all the pyglet/psychopy initialisation - neither are really designed for you to do this, so there would be some work here. But I'm not sure it's a good idea anyway to run scripts the way you are doing.

The PsychoPy app itself gets around the by launching each script in a new process. It means that you know the namespace is clean on each run. Running your script on top of the previous one can lead to some really hard-to-find bugs because you don't know in what state the previous script left the memory, graphics card and namespace.

cheers
Jon

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I and thousands of IPython users would disagree that it's a bad idea to work this way—the 'I' stands for "interactive" and having variables persist in memory is one of many extremely powerful interactive debugging tools built into the approach. You **do** have to know how to avoid the type of mistake you describe, of course—the answer is to think and to program modularly in terms of objects and functions, not in terms of "scripts" (same applies in matlab, which is also built this way).  No surprise re pyglet however—guess I will have to use separate processes anyway.

Comment: Haha, yes, I know the i stands for interactive. And I know thousands of people like to code interactively. I used to be one of them. Have fun with that, and feel free to submit code to the psychopy project if you find a way to do what you want.